# Combining functions which take callbacks

Tags: c++

I have a bunch of external functions I can not change (they read/write to a database or server). Every one of them takes some data object (that I don't want to copy for performance reasons), and a callback. Say,

```
void function1(DataObject &x, std::function<void(int)>> callback);
void function2(DataObject &x, std::function<void(int)>> callback);
void function3(DataObject &x, std::function<void(int)>> callback);
```

Now, the callbacks are not called back immediately (there is some event loop kind of thing going on in the background). We might make a `combineWithCallback` as follows:

```
class Combiner {
    int counter = 0;
    int result = 0;
    const DataObject &myX;

    Combiner(DataObject& x) : myX(x) {}
    
    void combineWithCallback(std::function<void(int)> callback) {
        counter = 3;
        sum = 0;
        function1(myX, [this](int result){ sum += result; counter--; });
        function2(myX, [this](int result){ sum += result; counter--; });
        function3(myX, [this](int result){ sum += result; counter--; });
        callback(sum);
    }
}
```

This creates a lot of boilerplate code for what essentially are just a couple of function calls. If they didn't use a callback but instead returned an `int` directly, I could write

```
int combine(DataObject &x) {
    return function1(x) + function2(x) + function3(x);
}
```

which I would much prefer. I don't need to make an additional class with member variables and methods, the function signatures are clearer and the code is easier to read.

Is there some way to be able to use the functions more like this last way, as if they returned an `int` directly?

I am not sure if async/await or promises/futures can help me here? I am afraid the usage of the event loop makes it impossible to use them (if I call `Promise.get()` the function will block, which will prevent the event loop from running, which will cause the callback to not get called...).

Comment: Why do you don't just call each function1..3 after each other? I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: @magunra Maybe it was not so clear from my question, but the callback might not be called immediately. So if I call the functions after each other I need to do some additional administration to keep track of when the result is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you need, but perhaps you can use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) as the callback, and have it call the next function in the chain.

Perhaps something like this:

```
int combine(DataObject& x)
{
    int result = 0;

    auto func3_callback = [&](int value)
    {
        result += value;
    };

    auto func2_callback = [&](int value)
    {
        result += value;
        function3(x, func3_callback);
    };

    auto func1_callback = [&](int value)
    {
        result += value;
        function2(x, func2_callback);
    };

    function1(x, func1_callback);

    return result;
}
```

---

Using `std::future` and `std::promise` it is possible to create a wrapper function that simplifies the usage of the functions.

Perhaps something like this:

```
int function1(DataObject& x)
{
    std::promise<int> promise;
    auto future = promise.get_future();

    function1(x, [promise = std::move(promise)](int value)
    {
        promise.set_value(value);
    });

    return future.get();
}
```

<sub>[Note that the code is untested]</sub>

Then do the same for `function2` and `function3`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! To be honest, I was hoping for something that has a closer resemblance to `function1(x) + function2(x) + function3(x)`. It still takes quite some effort to see what is going on in your example.

Comment: @Ruben It might be possible to create overloaded functions for `function1` etc. that wraps the callback-variants of the same function, to create the simple interface you want. Might be possible with asyncs, promises or futures or something similar.